# Wake up ESP-32 using matrix keypad

Tags: esp8266, keyboard, keypad

I want to realize a wireless keypad using ESP-32 and a matrix 4x3 keypad, connected via Bluetooth Low Energy to a master unit. I want to use deep sleep mode of ESP-32 when the keypad is not used but I need to wake up the ESP when a key is pressed, while not loosing the input. As far I understood, the matrix keypad needs the CPU running in order to understand which key has been pressed. Is there maybe some other way or component that I can use for this?
Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

There is a possibility to use lo power mcu that is build in the esp32 for reading the input while main cores are in deep sleep, but as far as i have been using it only with touch keypad.

It's not a full answer, but should help You.

https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf

Page 5, RTC block with ULP co-processor

also:
https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/system/ulp

https://blog.adafruit.com/2018/02/20/deep-sleep-tutorial-for-esp32-using-the-rtc-ulp-co-processor-and-two-lines-of-code/

This can handle the keypad feauture with wakeup for main core.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Welcome to electronics.stackexchange.com. Keep up the good work.

Comment: No problem, without help of others on this and many other forums or websites i would not have the knowledge I have. So if there is a way to give back to others what i have received when needed, i'm always willing to help. That's what community stands for, right? :)